# Routing not working properly in angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to add routing to my angular application but the routed component doesn't display the html at the router outlet place:

app.component.html:

```
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/login">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/plan">PLAN</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/login">HISTORY</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a routerLink="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PlanComponent } from './plan/plan.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'plan', component: PlanComponent},
    {path: '', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PlanComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes, 
      {enableTracing: true}
    ),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

plan.component.html

```
<p>plan works!</p>
```

login.component.html

```
<p>login works!</p>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SnearkyCalories</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am seeing is that the navigation bar is overriding the outlet tag. When I add some text under the list code, the html that is supposed to be displayed at router-outlet comes up.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Can you provide a specific example.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Both `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, ...` and `AppRoutingModule` being used...you want to do one or the other, not both. Can you include `AppRoutingModule` code?